# Rails 3 - sendgrid setup to support devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, sendgrid

I'm trying to get sendgrid running on my Rails 3 App with Devise, so devise can send out registration emails etc..

I added the following, config/setup_mail.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port => '25',
  :domain => "XXXXXXXXX.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name => "XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com",
  :password => "XXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Shouldn't that be enough for Rails + Devise to send out registration emails? Or do I need something else or a gem of some kind?

The logs show the email being generated but I don't see anything in the log about MAIL being sent successfully or erroring. And my sendgrid account still says 0/200 emails sent.

Is there a better way in Rails to see what's going on when it trys to send the email?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can erase the setup that you have.

```
heroku addons:create sendgrid:free
```

That is the only pieces of code you need to get email configured with heroku.

Make sure you have your host link setup which I think you did because it will cause it to crash but if you haven't:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.heroku.com' }
```

Actually this last lien is different on rails3 so watch out for that :)

The "config" line needs to be added to your "production.rb" file.

Comment: the thing is I don't want to set it up with Heroku but rather go use sendgrig directly myself as I need it to work locally.

Comment: always having to be special :). Sorry just too many variables that I haven't personally gone over recently.

Comment: The only thing I can come up with is on your `default_url_options` set it as the sendgrid url `smtp.sendgrid.net`

Comment: @AnApprentice have you figured out a solution to this yet? I'm trying to do the same thing as you are.

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for the same answer myself. In intializers/devise.rb I read:

```
  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"
```

I wonder if Devise has to be told to use Actionmailer.

Comment: It wasn't that. I used a JSON query to check the sendgrid credentials.

https://sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json?api_user=userhere@heroku.com&api_key=keyhere&to=test@domain.co.uk&toname=Destination&subject=Example%20Subject&text=testingtextbody&from=me@testdomain.co.uk

And that worked fine.  It seems I can get an email from Devise when I use the forgotpassword route, but not when I use the sign up form

Comment: OK, my problem was never that emails weren't being sent from heroku to sendgrid, my was that I had not set the Devise model options to include :confirmable (but I had :recoverable, which is why my recover emails worked).